# Post type cloud like tag cloud?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, tags

Anyone know if it's possible to create something similar to the wordpress built in tag cloud (wp_tag_cloud) but instead of displaying tags, display custom post types?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the `wp_generate_tag_cloud()` function? You'll need to feed it `$tags`, which is an array of objects with the link and term_id, set something like this.

```
$tags[]->link = $link;
$tags[]->id = $tag->term_id;
```

The term_id will only be used in the CSS...so don't sweat that too much.